# how to strore image in jsonobject

Tags: java, android, json, websocket, base64

i want to put an image in jsonobject so converted it to string using (base64-encodetostring) and it won't i think because of base64 encodetostring flag or idk i tried multiple ways to resolve the issue nothing helps and no solutions in the internet.

i've tried base64.DEFAULT flage and any single FLAG nothing helps because i think it's because the base64.encodetostring doesn't set an end to the string or idk exactly what is it

```
                pdp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bytes);

                byte[] bytes1=bytes.toByteArray();

                Pdp= Base64.encodeToString(bytes1,Base64.NO_WRAP|Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

and i put the exact Pdp string into jsono

```
                query.put("new_pdp",",pdp=cast('"+pdp+"==' as varbinary(max))");
            }else query.put("new_pdp","");
```

i logged it to the console and this is the result of the only encoded bytes :

```
_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_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-nHBhcmEAAAAAAAQAAAACMzMAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLW1sdWMAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAxlblVTAAAAIAAAABwARwBvAG8AZwBsAGUAIABJAG4AYwAuACAAMgAwADEANv_bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf_bAEMBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf_AABEIBRQFFAMBIgACEQEDEQH_xAAfAAEAAAYDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABAUGCQoLAwcIAQL_xAB-EAABAgYAAwIJBQgLCAwHAh8BAAIDBAUGBxEIEiEJMQoTFBUWIkFRYTJxgZHwFyMkJjahsdElJzU3QkZSVsHh8RgzNEVVYmaCQ0RUZGVncoOWorLndHV2d4aSlbMZGihTY5SXpra3x0eFtdI4OVeTxddYaHN4hIejpcLT5v_EABoBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQEGAwL_xAA-EQACAQEGAwUFBwQCAgMBAQAAAREhAgQxQVFhcZHwEhSBobEFIsHR8QMyNEJisuEVJFKicoITkiNTwkRD_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDP4REQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBFK5yqU6nj8OnpOU33iZm2s-sOI7_sFNEAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREARQ6iEAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBQsxHgwIXjo8bydvTbnEdO_pojr9XT4L5MRoEtCMePGEvLwB6xJ5W6AAG-hJ9wbon86pKHLGuEzNSlzBorWl0lT5kN1Pahhxq9ZZ6umAMHiobj0B5nknvA6jrU4JyaqUadbNTEw0Bs40SGg1rQAGjXcAAABoa9gXaVkNjQKC2WcIfkcvPlsmH9OYdBEG-8u8_iYAPTp07lI6PbFCqk1UY3iY8ajyw8hkpvyqJJDoG-MDRDdBe4NLmgRDyjqNs2QB2nLwYEtCECBBEvLwB6oA5W6AJOupJ95dsn8yAi0REAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBSmqz0aQptQnZeAZmZlZN022T36zixriW7HwY4nX8n4hRczGl5GAY8eKJeWgN9Yno3XsHtJHs1r4_FUZMUZtxPNRqomZaXldijSgLAZB7QC2tbDgTEIOwHb5Wg779gDqHx_wCGeUeUfhXl-_Lf8b67t-7f0_H4rvK0JiZnrepsxPxPKZkwtmc9Xc5rm--jfXTurSD09Tv0DqhKBa8nVIE1HnGzRlvKnyMg-TJpbZ-lt5OSuOaNPPjOZx2CNch2CXBdtS8GBLQhAgQRLy8AeqAOVugCTrqSfeXbJ_MgItERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBFCTEaBLQjHjxhLy8AesSeVugABvoSfcG6J_OqNdX6_PQTMU62XTEsNBhm6zDpbpwHoTDBhuAB0d87S36OiA5mObctUmxGI8zUOdfJGWcARPVSHrmiOPQFkLxgDW76ucPe4j7PeNuKcmKRBEaWo0qXSlYmxyAVB3yIlGh707XLF1FiAnTYnKNl-nyGmVmSpcSpxnCZgU6YqDXVqSqDS-qUCrV-Ix4c4aZDZbpAHI7ryPJewFjXME_nbVkajMmfl5iYlBND9mBJANZXWBg5WxDzHuLSOZns00DptARIMapMdIUotpdOlmmTM9LBsMkBvTzK6GCwBmuUxCA0AAAO11iqJOx5p1Qk5qYl5mZp014t0eWGgecFwD2ddRG9WuHXvI9nXimJjx0Y0ikkS_koIm5tuvwAAEgAOOi4gHvOiPhsqdycnLSMHyeVgNgQG9Q0Hod9_TZI6e8_nQEYiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAqdnrikJKaFPPlUzPlocZSRlYk9EAI3shobrQ79uaR12FC1OqRpma80UnTqgQfLJwFj20RjmN094IG3OG9AHrvZ3zACFPktFYKRRILZiqPBnXCbcTyl4ax1ZrkUCHEO3jvDRELgOVrTyhgHKbp8SXCPQa_LSwH-FmRJHvBIB_Od9N6B0p7IT9PqUHx8jMy000deeUcCPm3vfu66A30VOxajdsoJeNFpNNqUDR8sNKm4jXg6PrMbMNBcBrZ0CO_ehpS0SdqXHMPq0jPTVMqZBkZqJIT3mqqDuHi3gO5g7qCCByubvR2CgK5nZ2RkYJjT8zLSsD2vmphsNvf_AJ5Id7O4nSl0Cu0ediS8GDVaZMTEyHGTbJzrXl4DdkgMc7r07j1PQaVNy8vZVDmxLy8FtUqw7w0edaofn3s-7uI6d_Rc4gWxXI0tJTNJdTZotE9JsmpEUypBwOnOaOXn31cCOb2a5dgFAV6ioqlz0xTJqWoNWjTEyXcopNYiaJqI5dljywub4xrSN723WgSRylVqgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCKBnp-WpkrHnp6M2BKy7eZ7zrQaND5ySe4D6em1TvpV_svmCveT8v
```

and this is the logged output of jsonobject after putting the encoded bytes in it :

```
{
"operation":"edit_profile",
"username":"frsyescd",
"password":"123Ch@rif",
"new_email":"",
"new_pdp":"pdp=cast('_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_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-nHBhcmEAAAAAAAQAAAACMzMAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLW1sdWMAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAxlblVTAAAAIAAAABwARwBvAG8AZwBsAGUAIABJAG4AYwAuACAAMgAwADEANv_bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf_bAEMBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf_AABEIBRQFFAMBIgACEQEDEQH_xAAfAAEAAAYDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABAUGCQoLAwcIAQL_xAB-EAABAgYAAwIJBQgLCAwHAh8BAAIDBAUGBxEIEiEJMQoTFBUWIkFRYTJxgZHwFyMkJjahsdElJzU3QkZSVsHh8RgzNEVVYmaCQ0RUZGVncoOWorLndHV2d4aSlbMZGihTY5SXpra3x0eFtdI4OVeTxddYaHN4hIejpcLT5v_EABoBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQEGAwL_xAA-EQACAQEGAwUFBwQCAgMBAQAAAREhAgQxQVFhcZHwEhSBobEFIsHR8QMyNEJisuEVJFKicoITkiNTwkRD_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDP4REQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBFK5yqU6nj8OnpOU33iZm2s-sOI7_sFNEAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREARQ6iEAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBQsxHgwIXjo8bydvTbnEdO_pojr9XT4L5MRoEtCMePGEvLwB6xJ5W6AAG-hJ9wbon86pKHLGuEzNSlzBorWl0lT5kN1Pahhxq9ZZ6umAMHiobj0B5nknvA6jrU4JyaqUadbNTEw0Bs40SGg1rQAGjXcAAABoa9gXaVkNjQKC2WcIfkcvPlsmH9OYdBEG-8u8_iYAPTp07lI6PbFCqk1UY3iY8ajyw8hkpvyqJJDoG-MDRDdBe4NLmgRDyjqNs2QB2nLwYEtCECBBEvLwB6oA5W6AJOupJ95dsn8yAi0REAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBSmqz0aQptQnZeAZmZlZN022T36zixriW7HwY4nX8n4hRczGl5GAY8eKJeWgN9Yno3XsHtJHs1r4_FUZMUZtxPNRqomZaXldijSgLAZB7QC2tbDgTEIOwHb5Wg779gDqHx_wCGeUeUfhXl-_Lf8b67t-7f0_H4rvK0JiZnrepsxPxPKZkwtmc9Xc5rm--jfXTurSD09Tv0DqhKBa8nVIE1HnGzRlvKnyMg-TJpbZ-lt5OSuOaNPPjOZx2CNch2CXBdtS8GBLQhAgQRLy8AeqAOVugCTrqSfeXbJ_MgItERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBERAEREAREQBFCTEaBLQjHjxhLy8AesSeVugABvoSfcG6J_OqNdX6_PQTMU62XTEsNBhm6zDpbpwHoTDBhuAB0d87S36OiA5mObctUmxGI8zUOdfJGWcARPVSHrmiOPQFkLxgDW76ucPe4j7PeNuKcmKRBEaWo0qXSlYmxyAVB3yIlGh707XLF1FiAnTYnKNl-nyGmVmSpcSpxnCZgU6YqDXVqSqDS-qUCrV-Ix4c4aZDZbpAHI7ryPJewFjXME_nbVkajMmfl5iYlBND9mBJANZXWBg5WxDzHuLSOZns00DptARIMapMdIUotpdOlmmTM9LBsMkBvTzK6GCwBmuUxCA0AAAO11iqJOx5p1Qk5qYl5mZp014t0eWGgecFwD2ddRG9WuHXvI9nXimJjx0Y0ikkS_koIm5tuvwAAEgAOOi4gHvOiPhsqdycnLSMHyeVgNgQG9Q0Hod9_TZI6e8_nQEYiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiIAqdnrikJKaFPPlUzPlocZSRlYk9EAI3shobrQ79uaR12FC1OqRpma80UnTqgQfLJwFj20RjmN094IG3OG9AHrvZ3zACFPktFYKRRILZiqPBnXCbcTyl4ax1ZrkUCHEO3jvDRELgOVrTyhgHKbp8SXCPQa_LSwH-FmRJHvBIB_Od9N6B0p7IT9PqUHx8jMy000deeUcCPm3vfu66A30VOxajdsoJeNFpNNqUDR8sNKm4jXg6PrMbMNBcBrZ0CO_ehpS0SdqXHMPq0jPTVMqZBkZqJIT3mqqDuHi3gO5g7qCCByubvR2CgK5nZ2RkYJjT8zLSsD2vmphsNvf_AJ5Id7O4nSl0Cu0ediS8GDVaZMTEyHGTbJzrXl4DdkgMc7r07j1PQaVNy8vZVDmxLy8FtUqw7w0edaofn3s-7uI6d_Rc4gWxXI0tJTNJdTZotE9JsmpEUypBwOnOaOXn31cCOb2a5dgFAV6ioqlz0xTJqWoNWjTEyXcopNYiaJqI5dljywub4xrSN723WgSRylVqgCIiAIiIAiIgCIiAIiI"
}
```

Comment: Why are you compressing it before applying Base64?

Comment: what is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Looks like the base64 text string is getting truncated.

Comment: it was a Bitmap i needed to put it in the ByteArrayOutputStream then byte array so i can encode it

Comment: yes exactly and it closes the connection when i try to send it to my websocketserver with 1006 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding and encoding Base64 can be very memory intensive. If the image is on a server just grab url and query that.

Comment: @CharifBen'd if its a local file then just grab the URI of the image

Comment: no i meant when the users want to upload their image so i can store it in my server and store the url in my database (send the image to my server) the easy way is if they send it using json but like u said they can't, another way is to send it as bytes i think that's possible ?

Comment: @CharifBen'd are you using firebase?

Comment: @CharifBen'd where are the pictures being hosted?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it:

```
     String photoEncodedString = ""; 

    if (this.theBitmap != null) {           
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.theBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        photoEncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    String dataString = "[{";

    dataString = dataString + "\"PhotoImage\": \"" + photoEncodedString + "\" ";        
    dataString = dataString + ",\"Name\": \"" + etYourName.getText().toString() + "\" ";
    dataString = dataString + ",\"Email\": \"" + etEmail.getText().toString() + "\" ";
    dataString = dataString + ",\"Comments\": \"" + tvCommentsValue.getText().toString() + "\" ";

    dataString = dataString + "}]";

    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(dataString);
```

I think your .put error is related to incorrect formatting of your JSON.  You have

```
    { "operation":"edit_profile",
"username":"frsyescd",
"password":"123Ch@rif",
"new_email":"",
"new_pdp":",pdp=cast('_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD
```

Where there is a comma before pdp=cast.
Also "new_pdp":"pdp=cast(" wouldn't be valid JSON either.

I'm just saying that this is not valid JSON, so, it's going to cause an error somewhere:

```
 "new_pdp":",pdp=cast('_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD..._svmCveT8v
```

You are not finishing the string, based on what you posted above, you need it to look more like this for it to be valid JSON:

```
"new_pdp":"_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD..._svmCveT8v"
```

Here is my code again, but with the format of the JSON that you need:

```
 String photoEncodedString = ""; 

if (pdp != null) {           
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pdp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
    photoEncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

String dataString = "[{";

dataString = dataString + "\"operation\":\"edit_profile\" ";        
dataString = dataString + ",\"username\":\"frsyescd\" ";
dataString = dataString + ",\"password\":\"123Ch@rif\" ";
dataString = dataString + ",\"new_pdp\":\"" + photoEncodedString + "\""; 

dataString = dataString + "}]";

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(dataString);
```

Comment: hhh nice one love it, but why putting it with put function gives the error i'll wait for an answer if no answer i'll accept ur answer, ty, i'll give it a try.

Comment: { "operation":"edit_profile",
"username":"frsyescd",
"password":"123Ch@rif",
"new_email":",email='chd.hia@gmail.com'",
"new_pdp":",pdp=cast('_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD

Comment: no when i put comma with anything else encoded string i don't get any errors and it works fine

Comment: [{"operation":"edit_profile","username":"frsyescd","password":"123Ch@rif","new_email":"","new_pdp":",pdp=cast('\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/4gIoSUN
the same here it's getting truncated idk why exactly btw i tried without comma the same idk if it's the length too much or idk some chars :/

Comment: aah btw it gives me this exception at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
        at com.example.gc.myWebSocketClient$override.EditProfile(myWebSocketClient.java:180)
        at

Comment: look at this  String JsonString="{";
            JsonString+="\"operation\":\"edit_profile\"";
            JsonString+=",\"username\":\""+UserInfo.full_name+"\"";
            JsonString+=",\"password\":\""+old_password+"\"";
            if(!new_email.equals("")){
                JsonString+=",\"new_email\":\""+",email='"+new_email+"'"+"\"";
            }else JsonString+=",\"new_email\":\"\"";
            if(!pdp.equals("")){
                JsonString+=",\"new_pdp\":\",pdp=cast('"+pdp+"==' as varbinary(max))'\"";
            }else JsonString+=",\"new_pdp\":\"\"";

Comment: Also, JSON doesn't allow you to use single quotes to delineate strings.  So, in my code you will note that I'm escaping the double-quotes in the string literals so that I can wrap everything with double-quotes.

Comment: The whole ',pdp=cast(' thing has to be removed.

Comment: i did removed it and the same

Comment: and when i use it with other strings like email or anything it works

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show what you are using now?

Comment: i'm using that original code bc i got the same result

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above by @Haider Malik encoding and decoding base64 is memory insentive , as a solution you can use firestore from firebase as your DB provider and upload the images there.
an exemple to upload image will look like this :

```
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));

uploadTask = mountainsRef.putStream(stream);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
});StorageActivity.java
```

[Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)